# How do I open the current directory in mingw's msys in file explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mingw, msys

Assume I'm in:

```
$ pwd
/home/foo
```

Now I want to open up this /home/foo in Windows 10's file explorer. How do I do this?

Comment: What is the answer to this question?

Comment: @zielot's answer works. Thank you for reminding me, over a year late!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ start .
```

the "[start](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx)" command is a little like [xdg-open](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-open.html) for the Windows desktop (I believe even Windows 98 had the start command). If you are not working within an overlay that re-writes all of the directories to something like /c/Program\ Files/ then you can also pass directories and files to the command as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will test this once I am home and report back if it works!